# Using Left and Right navigation button to select different div frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

***Functionality:***

Users have the freedom to navigate between the 2 frames available for a picture shot. Hence, in the first frame, when the user clicks on the "Right" button; the "Left"button is hidden, the second frame will fadeIn while the first frame will fadeOut. Furthermore, when users are in the second frame and needs to navigate back to the first frame, the user will click on the "Left" button; the "Right" button will then be hidden, the second frame will fadeOut while the first frame will fadeIn.

***What has been done:***

I have created the 2 frame `<div>`s and also the method call for the left button and the right button.

***Issue:***

In the first frame, the left arrow is still hidden, as I have set the class="hidden" for the left arrow. However, when the user navigates to the second frame, the left arrow is still "hidden" while the right arrow is still "shown" when it should be hidden.

Hence, how do I set the conditional check for the 2 frames, such that when the user navigates to the second frame, the "right" arrow is hidden and only the "left arrow is showing", while in the first frame, the "right" arrow is showing and the "left" arrow is hidden.

```js
function Left() {
  $('#Photoframe02').fadeOut({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Photoframe02').animate({
    'left': '1921px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
    queue: false
  });

  $('#Photoframe01').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Photoframe01').animate({
    'left': '0px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
    queue: false
  });
}

function Right() {
  $('#Photoframe01').fadeOut({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Photoframe01').animate({
    'left': '1921px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
    queue: false
  });

  $('#Photoframe02').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Photoframe02').animate({
    'left': '0px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
    queue: false
  });
}

//I think this is a wrong method call to check frame, as both IDs are different
function CheckFrame(page) {

  if ($("#Photoframe01").turn("page") = 2) {
    // If the page we are currently on is not the first page, reveal the back button
    $("#LeftSide").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#RightSide").addClass("hidden");
    console.log("RoleModels LeftSide is shown");
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Active_Camera" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=5; top:0px; left:0px; ">

  <img id="Photoframe01" class="hidden" style=" position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; z-index:5; top:0px; left:0px;" src="lib/img/Photoframe01.png" />
  <img id="Photoframe02" style=" position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; z-index:5; top:0px; left:1921px;" src="lib/img/Photoframe02.png" />
  <button id="LeftButton" onclick="Left()">
    <img style="width: 250px; height:250px" src="lib/img/Nav/Left.png">
  </button>
  <button id="RightButton" onclick="Right()">
    <img style="width: 250px; height:250px" src="lib/img/Nav/Right.png">
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo ok. but the navigation arrow is still posing the same issues

Comment: As soon as I get my hands on a pc I will try to help you.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo alright, I ahve managed to solve my issue, however, if you do have a better solution than what I have derived. Maybe you could share here. Newer and simpler and cleaner coding is always good to learn. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own issue.

I have employed the method of having an Index attached to each navigation button. Secondly, I have put the available frames into an array, such that it can be called from a list. Hence, I find this method to be simpler and cleaner.

```js
var selectedFrameIndex = 1;

var framelist = ["Photoframe01.png", "Photoframe02.png", , "Photoframe03.png", , "Photoframe04.png"];

function selectFrame(flag) {
  if (flag == "1") {
    selectedFrameIndex--;

  } else if (flag == "2") {
    selectedFrameIndex++;
  }
  if (selectedFrameIndex <= 0) {
    selectedFrameIndex = framelist.length;
  } else if (selectedFrameIndex > framelist.length) {
    selectedFrameIndex = 1;
  }
  $("#Photoframe").attr("src", "lib/Photoframe0" + selectedFrameIndex + ".png");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="Photoframe" class="hidden" style=" position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; z-index:6; top:0px; left:0px; display: inline-block; " src="lib/Photoframe01.png" />

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1080" id="photo_stream">
    <tr>
      <td width="1080">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080" style="position:absolute; z-index:5; top:0; left:0; margin:auto; display:none;"></canvas>

        <button id="CameraActiveButton" onclick="TakePicture()">
          <img src="lib/img/PAGE04/SNAPNOW.png">
        </button>

        <button id="LeftButton" onclick="selectFrame('2')">
          <img style="width: 250px; height:250px" src="lib/img/PAGE04/Nav/Left.png">
        </button>
        <button id="RightButton" onclick="selectFrame('1')">
          <img style="width: 250px; height:250px" src="lib/img/PAGE04/Nav/Right.png">
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```